# Matlab MEX C++ two files with same name in different folders

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile some C++ files that have the same name (fileA) but located in different folders (folder1 and folder2), lets say:

```
folder1/fileA.cpp
folder1/fileB.cpp
```

and

```
folder2/fileA.cpp
folder2/fileC.cpp
```

These files contain different classes.

But `mex` creates the objects for both folder1/fileA.cpp and folder2/fileA.cpp in the same folder so when it tries to generate the final W32 file some classes are missing.

Is there any way of telling mex to do not "flatten" the folders structure and then not overwriting one fileA.obj with the other fileA.obj?

---

All proposed solutions end up with the same basic idea: **prepare my own compilation process** (i.e. *Makefiles* or similar). *My problem* with this solution is that they are not the same for Linux, Windows, 32 or 64 bits,... and are not easy to maintain. That's why I would have preferred to have a solution based on `mex` but seems that it is something not supported so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this kind of flexibility you will need to follow the conventional UNIX Makefile based strategy of seperately compiling each object file.

For example, for each source file you can use `mex -c` with the `-output` directory option specified as in Oli's answer to create the object files - followed by a single final mex for the output function which use these object files.

I can't think of any other way to acheive what you want (with a single call of the mex function).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify the output directory:

```
mex folder1/filleA.cpp -output folder1/fileA
```

Comment: I'm actually compiling all the files with one single invocation to mex in order to finally generate the mex. As far as I understand your solution generates the output for one single file but not all of them  together. Correct?

Comment: correct, but there is only one output per mex command anyway, no?

Comment: Yes but one `mex` file might include multiple `obj` files. If `mex` script saves all `obj` files in the same folder (for latter procede to link them in one single `mexw32`), one is overwritten by the other and therefore the content of the first gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
mymex(list_of_files);
```

with mymex.m being:

```
function mymex(list_of_files)
  for n = 1:length(list_of_files),
    mex list_of_files(n) -output % do some string manipulation on list_of_files(n) here to get the right output file location
  end
end
```

Comment: Doing that what I get are multiple `mexw32` files instead of all of them linked in one single file.
So far I'm doing something similar with `-c` for just generating the objects and then invoke a final mex for linking them in the `mexw32`. But this is pretty manual and seems strange to me that mex actually flattens folder structure (all intermediate object in one single folder instead of preserving original structure to avoid name collision).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually compile and build mex files without running matlab. The process behind it is a normal compilation (creating object files and linking them).
And for a normal compilation, it is no problem to have objects files that have the same name (in different directories). 
I would agree with robince that doing a makefile can help you achieve what you want, but if makefiles are not you cup of tea, just a simple shell/batch script will do with a succession of compilation commands (see below).

You are probably giving several files as arguments to mex. 
To understand what matlab is really doing, you can run it with the flag -v

```
  mex -v folder1/file1.cpp folder1/file2.cpp
```

Look at the compilation commands that appears in Matlab's command window "-> gcc etc.". You can run them in a command prompt. For each file, Matlab simply calls the compiler with (quite) some flags and include paths. As you know, this generates objects files and at the end, everything is linked together. This stage fails because matlab calls the compiler without specifying an output, so by default the compiler put the objects files in the current directory.

To avoid that you have to specify an output file like this (see the -o flag):

```
  gcc -c MATLABFLAGS folder1/File.cpp -o folder1/File.o
```

If you have a lot of files, that's were the Makefile gets handy:

```
  %Folder/.o: %.c
     $(CC) -I$(MATINC)  $(CCFLAGS) -c $<
```

At the end, for the linking stage, you'll have to enter the real location of your objects files:

```
 gcc MATLAB_LINK_FLAGS -o Final_MexFile.mex* Folder1/File.o Folder2/File.o   etc...
```

And the mex is compiled.
Maybe there is a gcc option to avoid all of that that you could put in your mexoptions file. I'll be glad to know it! Otherwise, I would recommend using a Makefile.
I hope it helps!